# Interaction between components in Use Case diagrams UML

Tags: android, server, uml, use-case

I've created an android app and a server to send commands to a driving simulator.
The server is running on a raspberry while the simulator is running on a pc. The flow is as follows (example for the brake command):

1. The user taps the brake button on the android app
2. The android app sends a message over bluetooth low energy to the server
3. The server sends a message over socket ethernet to the driving simulator
4. The car in the simulator brakes

I'm having troubles representing this use case in UML, in particular about the interaction between the components. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you are primarily concerned about showing the interactions between the components. For this purpose, I suggest to use an [activity diagram](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/activity-diagrams.html) (and not a use case diagram which you seem to have in mind). You can use swimlanes for showing which action takes place in which component, roughly like this:

[image]

On the other hand, if you are more concerned about the deployment and the physical interfaces between the components, I suggest to use a [deplyoment diagram](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/deployment-diagrams.html), roughly like this:

[image]

As you see, each diagram focuses on a certain aspect of the problem, so you will typically need more than one diagram for your model.

Answer (score 0):

You need to shake off thinking in functions and find the added value. In this case it's clearly the possibility to brake a car. And that's  the actor --- use case:

`Driver` --- `Brake Car`

All the functional description would go into an activity diagram or a textual UC description.